# LPAD with zeroes not getting applied to the string

Tags: c#

I am trying to pad zeroes to the left of the string. I need to generate basically numbers in the following format. FOr some reason it prints the number  like this 10,20, ... 180
For e.g.

0010,0020,0030,0040,0050 ... 0180

Logic

```
var col = 0;
 for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++)
    {
         col = i*10;
         col.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine(col);
```

Comment: You are discarding the padded string (not assigned to anything)

Comment: catch it if you can.

Comment: side note: `col.ToString("0000")` is another way to accomplish the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the updated format/value to the variable before printing it to the screen.

```
 var col = 0;
 
 for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++)
    {
         col = i*10;
         // need to assign the value to the col or you can just print it directly to screen in the loop like line below this one
         string formattedNumber = col.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');

         // or just print the formatted string
         Console.WriteLine(col.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'));
         // or 
         Console.WriteLine(formattedNumber);
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine(col);
```

Comment: that won't compile. c# is mostly type safe.

Comment: col = col.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'); doesnt compile

Comment: I updated it.  You can assign the formatted value to a new string variable and print out that variable.  Or the writeline directly with col.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'));  should work as well.